# Dynamic loading of controller files based on Backbone.history.fragment

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I am building a application with has over 50 modules. Is is good idea to dynamically load controller + router using require function ? Following is my sudo code from app.js file which I am using along with require.js and marionette

```
app.on("initialize:after", function(){
  if(Backbone.history){
    Backbone.history.start();

    /* For now I am considering the app with have only single 
    level routing, something like http://localhost#module and
    app will always call list method from controller */    

    var moduleName = Backbone.history.fragment;
    var controllerFile = "app/controller/" + moduleName + "controller";

    require([controllerFile], function() {
      app.trigger( moduleName + ':' + 'list');
    }
  }
})
```

My controller file contains router and it will directly call views after initializing the necessary models. The only risk I see using this method that require function might get called before the controller file is full loaded. I have not added any safeguards in the code, which I will do when I understand if this is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your router should contain controller.  Not the other way around.

Since you have 50 modules, I suggest you take a look at `Marionette.module` and its `addInitializer ()` and `startWithParent` to bootstrap all these modules as and when you need them to load.

You can use both requireJS and Marionette.module without issue.